# How to calculate percentage within a value range in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, math, formula, percentage

I have a value that i need to translate to a percentage given a certain set of rules.

```
VALUE=X
```

Where X can be anything starting from 0

If:

```
X > 200
```

the result of my function should be 100 (percent).

If:

```
X < 200 AND >= 100
```

the result should be between 100 and 50 (percent). 
Example: X=150 would be 75%

If:

```
X < 100 AND >= 80
```

the result should be between 50 and 25 (percent).
Example: X=90 would be 37.5%

And if:

```
X < 80
```

the result should be between 25 and 0 (percent).

My approach in PHP would be something like

```
if($value > 200) return 100;
if($value > 100 && $value < 200) return ???;
```

... and so on.

Wherein ??? obviously stands for the formula i don't know how to set up.

Is there a way to do this in one single formula?
And even if not - what is the mathematical approach to this problem?

I know it is very basic but it seems i skipped too many maths lessons in primary school.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function can be defined piecewisely:

[image]

Graphically, this is represented with four straight lines of different gradients. While there isn't a way to represent this function without separate pieces, implementing the above is quite easy.

In PHP, this function can be written as:

```
function f($x) {
    if ($x >= 200)
        return 100;
    if ($x >= 100 && $x < 200)
        return 50 + 50 * (($x - 100) / 100);
    if ($x >= 80 && $x < 100)
        return 25 + 25 * (($x - 80) / 20);
    if ($x < 80)
        return 25 * ($x / 80);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late modification but i decided to change the question to be PHP related because that's what i use and because i found that similar questions received bad votes because they were too abstract. Unfortunately my maths skills are so terrible i don't even know how to apply this practically.

Comment: What for the case where x == 200? (That case is currently not taken care of....). +3 mn:  It is now!

Comment: That case is obvious, even to me. if($x>=200) return 100;

Comment: Despite feeling guilty for having work done for me in this case, thank you for translating this to PHP. Beautifully solved!

Comment: No problem. I've just updated the answer to fix a number of errors.

Comment: Just for general convenience - update your answer to contain $x instead of x.

Comment: By the way, if you copied the code, please come back and copy it again, as I've found and corrected some more clumsy errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine which range you should be in. Then:

- Subtract the bottom of the range.
- Divide by the length of the range.
- Multiply by the number of points difference over the range.
- Add the number of points at the bottom of the range.

So X from 100 to 200 gives a score from 100 to 50. The bottom of the range is 100; the size of the range is 100 (200 - 100), and the score goes from 100 at the beginning to 50 at the end, so the difference is -50. Therefore `-50 * ($value - 100) / 100 + 100` would work, or simplifying, `-0.5 * ($value - 100) + 100` or `150 - $value * 0.5`.

Working another example, from 80 to 100: the bottom of the range is 80, the size of the range is 20, and the score goes from 25 to 50 (difference: -25). You get `-25 * ($value - 80) / 20 + 25`, which simplifies to `-1.25 * ($value - 80) + 25` or `125 - $value * 1.25`

Comment: Answer here already but i'll upvote this for explaining the issue in a readable way. Thank You!